# Check all Check boxes in all pages of pagination

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have 100 records displaying in pagination when select all checkbox is checked all the 100 records in different pagination should get selected

Comment: Currently I'm using this [Demo](http://http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/Selection/grid-selection-checkbox)

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problem?  (ex: What have you tried so far and what is the specific error / problem)

Comment: Currently I'm using this [Snippet](https://dojo.telerik.com/oTESocIZ/2)